# Possible range of an angle in a triangle based on Hinge theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was solving me homework (Don't get me wrong I don't need help with my homework) on geometry when I saw a question about possible range of an angle.

Consider two triangles $△ABC, △EFG$ with two pairs of congruent sides. The angle between  the congruent sides in the $△ABC$ is $60$. For the other triangle the angle is $x$.

If the the third side of $△ABC$ is $50$, and the third side of $△EFG$ is $49$, then what is the range of possible values of $x$?

By Hinge theorem, $x<60$. Also $0 <x$, so $0<x<60$. Solved?

But I am not sure how $x$ can be close to $0$, because $49, 50$ are close, so $x$ and $60$ have to be close.

How can you show that any angle $x$ between $0$ and $60$ can actually make the third side of $△EFG$ equals $49$?

Can you show this for  a more general case of triangles( Like instead of 60, any angle and instead of 49, 50 any lengths)

Comment: "two pairs of congruent sides" means what?

Comment: Like AB and EF are congruent, and BC and FG are congruent

Comment: I think I was ambiguous in that statement :)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-2cos(60)ab%3D+50%5E2,a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-2cos(48)ab%3D49%5E2

Comment: The equation is for finding the length of the third side based on the sides a, b and the angle between them.

Comment: Right, 48 degrees appears to work. I'll check my work to see if I can find the correct minimum.

Comment: It works for up to 58.6  but it doesn't work for 58.7 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-2cos(60)ab%3D+50%5E2,a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-2cos(58.7)ab%3D49%5E2

Comment: Wasn't the lower bound for your previous calculation 58.7 or something like that? Except it is the upper bound here.

Comment: I had solved those equations before I asked the question(for x,n,c,d where x,n are the measure of The angles in ABC, and EFG respectively, and c,d are the measure of the side opposite to the angles respectively ), but the solution could have had imaginary solutions so I was trying to figure out how it will always have positive real solutions, But I now found counterexamples. The problem is solved.

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment, the range of $x$ is
$$0 < x \le \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2599}{5000}\right)$$
so $x$ has an absolute maximum value, which, in degrees, is approximately $58.68116315$.